# Dynamically set Analysis Services Connection Manager in a Fooreach loop [SSIS 2008]

Tags: ssis

I am storing connection strings for "Analysis Services Connection Manager" in a database table and on run time i am fetching them all, storing in an object and iterating through them inside a Foreach loop. Variable gets updated with a new connection string in each iteration but somehow my "Analysis Services Processing Task" fails with "Invalid Connection String" Error.

Is there any way we can set  set Analysis Services Connection Manager Dynamically. I can done this with OLEDB connections and that works. But somehow it's not working for Analysis Services Connection manager. Can anyone please share his/her experience ?

Many thanks,

Comment: Your method sounds fine, I take it you are using a expression on the Analysis Services for the `ConnectionString` and then using the variable stored from the `ForEachLoop`. Have you tried putting the `DelayValidation` on?

Comment: Yes that's true but as soon as "Analysis Service Processing Task" starts execution, it fails with "Invalid Connection String Error".

Comment: I would try splitting the AS Task off into a new SSIS package, which is where I would apply the Connection & Config.  Then in the main package, I would use an Execute Package task to call this new package.

Comment: But execute package task has to be in side For-each loop and i need to change the connection string in each iteration . Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's old, but I ran across your post when I had a similar problem.  If you look at the processing command generated by the processing task, you can actually see the DDL being executed.  Embedded in the DDL is the name of the database, so if you want to swap databases, you ALSO have to modify the DDL in addition to just changing the connection string.  I worked around my issue by changing the processing task over to a DDL task and used an expression/variable to set the correct database name in the DDL.